# How do I split a number into decimal and fractionary in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Microsoft Excel, I have a calculus result; for example 8,74.

How can I say to Excel to show me just the fractional part 0,74?

Answer (score 4):

Formula `TRUNC(a1)` will show the whole part of cell `A1`, so to get the fractional part, use `A1-TRUNC(a1)`

Just beware that for negative numbers, like -2.3, this will give you -0.3, not 0.3. To take care of that case, try using `ABS(a1-TRUNC(a1))`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MOD function with a divisor of 1, e.g. with 8,74 in A1

`=MOD(A1;1)`

I'm assuming that your region requires semi-colon ; as a separator

Comment: +1 But there seems to be [problem with negative numbers](http://i.imgur.com/iES2ZkE.png) though. `=MOD(-8.74, 1)` returns 0.26. Changing the 2nd argument to `-1` (at least when dealing with negative values) should be able to fix it.

Comment: I think you could also use `=MOD(A1;SIGN(A1))`